# The best method to implement serach Android listview

Tags: android, listview, search

I have implemented searching listview in my android project. First application loads data from mysql using PHP - JSON into listview using async method. This works fine if response is fast and the list contains not to much items. But my list contains more than 550 items.  It takes while to load data into list. So I'm wondering is there any better or faster method to load into list?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is here :

- http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

An easy way is to attach an OnQueryTextListener on your searchview.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();              

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    return true;
}
```

After you have to implement onQueryTextSubmit() and onQueryTextChange() method.

```
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.getTextFilter();
    }

    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it like pages so for example first request will get 10 elements then with load more button "or without it using scroll listener on the listview" to get the next 10 elements.

for first approach : load more with button 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

and for the second approach : load more without button
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html

Comment: Thanks to all I will try with button for loading more data.